# convert grouped dataframe to dictionary with apply/lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a df like this

```
     A   B       C
0   11  one      5
1   11  two      7
2   11  three    9
3   22  one      11
4   22  two      13
```

I'd like to convert this df to dictionary like this:

```
{11: [(one, 5), (two, 7), (three, 9)]
 22: [(one, 11), (two, 13)]} 


df_dict = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda y: {(x.B, x.C) for i, x in y.iterrows()})
```

The actual results I got from this code:

```
11    {(one, 5), (two, 7), (three, 9)}
22    {(one, 11), (two, 13)}
```

Comment: `df.set_index('A').apply(tuple,1).groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_dict()
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.B, x.C))).to_dict()

{11: [('one', 5), ('two', 7), ('three', 9)], 22: [('one', 11), ('two', 13)]}
```